# Java spring: erro Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, model

Estou tendo problema ao realizar o método list de traduções do documento, não estou entendendo o motivo do erro, segue código:

```
Translation.java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Translation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;


    //muitas traduções para um documento
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="id_document", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    private Document document;
}

Document.java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Document {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    //um documento com muitas traduções
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="document")
    private Set<Translation> translations;
}
```

O erro:

> ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by
>   Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError);  nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
>   model.Translation["document"]->model.Document["translations"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->model.Translation["document"]->cmodel.Document["translations"]....

Obrigada

Comment: Realmente encontrei o problema neste link, obrigada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema foi solucionado adicionando as anotações `@JsonManagedReference` em document e `@JsonBackReference` em translation, exemplo abaixo:

```
    Document.java
     ...
    //um documento com muitas traduções
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="document")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Translation> translations;


    Translation.java
     ...
    //muitas traduções para um documento
    @ManyToOne()
    @JsonBackReference
    private Document document;
```